# django, Adding a passcode to restrict who can register on my website

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have a registration page that I want to restrict who can register to my website.

views.py:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        passcode = PassCodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            passcode == "FreedomLivesHere"
            if passcode == 'passcode':
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                messages.error(request, f'Passcode incorrect, please try again!')
        else:
            messages.error(request, f'Oops I did it again! Please try again later.')
            return redirect('register')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        passcode = PassCodeForm()

    context = {
        'passcode':passcode,
        'form':form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class PassCodeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Passcode 
        fields = ['passcode']
```

When I run my registeration page I get the else statement: 'Oops I did it again! please try again later.'), whats the best way of adding a passcode field that matches a string. Also, depending on the passcode string. Its going to create either an active, admin, or staff permission type. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You get error `Oops I did it again! please try again later` because you have two form action on the same url. So one form will be always invalid. You cant send more than one form at on time. Add field password to form UserRegisterForm and create validator that will be check entered password.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute